# Spring-cloud Zuul retry when instance is down and forward t other other available instance

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

using 'Dalston.RELEASE' for spring-cloud-dependencies, with spring boot '1.5.2.RELEASE'.

In my setup, I have

1. eureka server
2. zuul gateway server
3. 2 instances of a service [cloud-client] and have registered the eureka server

My zuul Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableEurekaClient
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
    }
}
```

and application.yml is:

```
 zuul:
  SendErrorFilter:
    error:
      disable: true
  routes:
    test:
      path: /testclient/**
      retryable: true
      serviceId: cloud-client
ribbon:
  MaxAutoRetries: 0
  MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 3
  OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true
```

When the two services are running, The load balancing is done properly through zuul without any issues.
when an instance is killed, Zuul is still trying to fulfil the request using the same service which is down. However if waited till the eureka registry is fetched after shutting down the instance, requests are fulfilled with the other instances which are 'UP'.

```
2017-05-06 19:03:10.105 ERROR 54389 --- [nio-8900-exec-8] c.n.mail.pdc.gateway.zuul.ErrorFilter    : request failed,reason:com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:227) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.util.ZuulRuntimeException: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

I read the issue[https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1290#issuecomment-242204614] and find this issue is fixed.

But Why I still have this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` whether it has spring-retry as a dependency or not.

The implementation about retrying http request inside zuul (actually ribbon) and also other components like feign were rebuilt based on `spring-retry` from Camden.SR6 and Dalston.RELEASE. And you must add spring-retry dependency EXPLICITLY in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`. For example :

```
    compile('org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.0.RELEASE')
```

In these releases, retryable-related beans are conditionally loaded only if it found spring-retry class. If not, just normal - not retryable - implementation is used instead. You can check related code [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonClientConfiguration.java#L146).

Comment: Adding sprign-retry dependency helped me solve this issue. Thanks ! Can we also configure zuul to retry only for specific error codes and configure number of retries also ? Adding ribbon.MaxAutoRetries and ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer doesn't seem to work for me.